# Can OSGi components be deployed in any Servlet containers?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

Can OSGi components be deployed to any Container like Tomcat/Websphere/JBoss..etc ? (just as we deploy a WAR file) or do they require any special libraries or OSGi containers to run the OSGi components ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just expose the "component" classes, you can treat the jar files as .. jar files.

If you consider the OSGi "component" as a "bundle" exposing some services and doing something, then answer is "no". You need an OSGi container (Karaf,  WebSphere Liberty, Carbon, Glassfish, JBoss WildFly ...).

However - as you can see, some application servers provide OSGi support natively.

Answer (score 1):

OSGi components (I guess you mean bundles) require an OSGi framework to run in. So a plain servlet container will not work. Some versions of JBoss provide support for OSGi though.

Comment: Eclipse has a servlet bridge that allows you to run an OSGi framework via a servlet. This should work for any servlet container.